# Setting a variable from a numbered array, using the array index number and choice.exe

Tags: batch-file

I have many variables in a batch file, as seen below:

```
set var1=aaaaa 
set var2=bbbbb 
set var3=ccccc 
set var4=ddddd 
...
...
set var20=mmmmm

choice /c abcd.....p /n /m "your choice"
set index=%errorlevel%

set newVar=%var%%index% && does not work
```

How can I set the `newVar` variable to have a value depending on the `index numeral` 
and getting that number from a `choice` statement, via the `errorlevel`?

An example:
If the errorlevel is `1` then newVar should have the value `aaaaa`
If the errorlevel is `2` then newVar should have the value `bbbbb` and so on....

Comment: You should use array http://superuser.com/questions/191224/populating-array-in-dos-batch-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
choice /c abcd /n /m "your choice"
CALL SET "value=%%var%errorlevel%%%"
ECHO value=%value%
```

I've reduce the choices to a..d for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You it works. Because I need variable "index" later in program I modified like this

```
choice /c abcd /n /m "your choice"
set index=%errorlevel%
CALL SET "value=%%var%index%%%"
ECHO value=%value%
```

Now I don't know how to list them in two columns like below

var1=aaaaa        var2=bbbb

var3=ccccc        var4=dddd

.....
etc.